# How to left justify text in a tableview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I have the following layout:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_column="1" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

But the output is as follows:

[image]

I'm not sure which property i need to set?

Comment: `TableRow`s are basically just horizontal `LinearLayout`s, so you can use `layout_weight`s to get evenly sized children in each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Please check this [tutorial](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/tablelayout)

Comment: your answer did not fix the issue. It seems that the second column starts further out when the textview is longer based on username!?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_weight=".1"`, `android:layout_width="0dp"` and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `Textview` of `TableRow`

Try this code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Output of above code is like:

[image]